# What's the easiest way to fill my 3d enviornment with temporary graphics?

Tags: 3d

Currently I am starting a 3D game with C# but I don't have a designer yet nor any images or anything or any money to invest on it.

I would like to develop it using some sort of placeholder or whatever to fill the graphics so I can make at least the basics of it and later simply switch for the real thing.

Should the place holders be actual sample images or can I use for example a ball to represent a body (what will be the impact of it later when I switch to the actual body it self)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest placeholder graphics are those that you just whip up in code.  For a 3D game, write something code to generate a plane, a box, a sphere, a cylinder.  Bam, now you have enough stuff to make a game!